# Flutter Crashlytics log caught exception

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

Looking for some clarification as to how one can log caught exceptions using flutter's `firebase_crashlytics` package.

If I understand correctly (and from running some sample code) `Crashlytics.instance.log('text');` will only add logs to the next crash report, rather than send off a non-fatal issue itself.

I'm looking for functionality which is equivalent to `Crashlytics.logException(e);` on Android, e.g.

```
try {
  throwException();
} catch (e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

which allows you to log caught exceptions so they appear as non-fatal issues in the Crashlytics dashboard.

Is this currently possible with flutter's firebase_crashlytics package?

Is calling `Crashlytics.instance.recordError('text', StackTrace.current)` the way to achieve this for now?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

`Crashlytics.instance.recordError()` is the equivalent of `Crashlytics.logException()`

If you dig into the Flutter [firebase_crashlytics](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics) source code, you can actually see what Android APIs are involved.

Flutter’s [recordError()](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics/lib/src/firebase_crashlytics.dart#L207) invokes the method [Crashlytics#onError](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/crashlytics/firebasecrashlytics/FirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.java#L37) in the Android library.

And tracing Crashlytics#onError, you’ll see that it goes to `Crashlytics.logException(exception);`

Additional note, you’ll also notice why `Crashlytics.instance.log()` *”will only add logs to the next crash report”*. These logs are added to a `ListQueue<String> _logs` which is then packaged into the next call of `recordError()`

A snippet of Flutter’s [invocation of Crashlytics.logException()](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_crashlytics/lib/src/firebase_crashlytics.dart#L256):

```
_recordError(...) {
     ...
     final String result = await channel
          .invokeMethod<String>('Crashlytics#onError', <String, dynamic>{
        'exception': "${exception.toString()}",
        'context': '$context',
        'information': _information,
        'stackTraceElements': stackTraceElements,
        'logs': _logs.toList(),
        'keys': _prepareKeys(),
      });
}
```

And some reference [notes for Crashlytics.logException()](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html):

> To reduce your users’ network traffic, Crashlytics batches logged
> exceptions together and sends them the next time the app launches.
>
> For any individual app session, only the most recent 8 logged
> exceptions are stored.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the accepted answer, `Crashlytics.instance.recordError()` has now been deprecated for the new method `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(exception, stack)`.

**BONUS TIP:**
I had this problem where all the logged exceptions are grouped under the same issue in Crashlytics dashboard. These might be different crashes of the same or different code components. Due to this, I had to manually go through each instance of the crash to verify.

[image]

From my own testing, I found out the grouping is based on the top-most line in the stack trace you passed into the method above. Luckily, Dart has an easy way to get the current stack trace using `StackTrace.current`.

So to properly group the issues: get the current stack trace ***at the time of the exception*** and pass it in `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(exception, stack)`.

Hope this helps someone out there, I looked everywhere on the internet for a similar issue but can't find any.